# How can I have subfloats with knitr in LyX?

Tags: lyx, knitr

I have two `knitr` chunks in `LyX` that work fine by themselves in their separate floats (this post applies to both figures and tables). But when I try to put them in as subfloats (by selecting both and going to Insert > Float > Table or Insert > Float > Figure), I get errors.

For information on subfloats, see User Guide section 4.6.2.1 Figure Floats.

I'm using LyX 2.0.3 and svn, and knitr version .3

Comment: I suggest you add a tag `knitr` to the post as well.

Comment: @Yihui I would like to, but there is no `knitr` tag and you have to have 300 reputation to create a tag. Once someone creates the tag I will come back and add it.

Comment: Perhaps this thread is related to the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940336/opinion-about-generating-and-cross-referencing-knitr-plots-in-lyx/68942326#68942326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a LyX example is the best way to answer your question; [I have created one here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/raw/master/inst/examples/knitr-subfloats.lyx) (right click and save as a LyX document). Note you have to install the development version of knitr: https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme. Below is a screenshot of the output:

[image: use subfloats with knitr in LyX]